# Oracle DB 18c - Revoke user's privileges from accessing other user's PUBLIC schemas

Tags: database, oracle

I created db users for Oracle db (18c, edition 18.0.0.0.0) following the below script:

```
CREATE USER username  IDENTIFIED BY username  ;
-- ROLES
GRANT "CONNECT" TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
ALTER USER username  DEFAULT ROLE "CONNECT";
-- SYSTEM PRIVILEGES
GRANT DROP ANY TRIGGER TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT DROP ANY SEQUENCE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT CREATE TRIGGER TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT ALTER ANY PROCEDURE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT CREATE ANY PROCEDURE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT EXECUTE ANY INDEXTYPE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT DEBUG CONNECT SESSION TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT ALTER SESSION TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT MERGE ANY VIEW TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT CREATE ANY INDEX TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT ALTER ANY MATERIALIZED VIEW TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT CREATE INDEXTYPE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT DEBUG ANY PROCEDURE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT CREATE ANY SEQUENCE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT ALTER ANY TABLE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT DELETE ANY TABLE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT ALTER ANY SEQUENCE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT DROP ANY MATERIALIZED VIEW TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT DROP ANY TABLE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT SELECT ANY SEQUENCE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT MANAGE TABLESPACE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT CREATE TYPE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT CREATE TABLESPACE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT SELECT ANY TRANSACTION TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT LOCK ANY TABLE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT DROP ANY TYPE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT QUERY REWRITE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT EXECUTE ANY PROCEDURE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT CREATE SYNONYM TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT DEBUG CONNECT ANY TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT CREATE SEQUENCE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT CREATE ANY INDEXTYPE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT DROP ANY INDEX TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT UPDATE ANY TABLE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT DROP ANY VIEW TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT ALTER TABLESPACE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT ALTER ANY TRIGGER TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT CREATE ANY VIEW TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT IMPORT FULL DATABASE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT READ ANY TABLE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT INSERT ANY TABLE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT CREATE ANY MATERIALIZED VIEW TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT ALTER ANY TYPE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT DROP ANY PROCEDURE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT DROP ANY INDEXTYPE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT CREATE ANY TRIGGER TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT CREATE ANY TABLE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT CREATE ANY TYPE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT ALTER DATABASE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT DROP TABLESPACE TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
```

The issue is that each one of them can select Schema Browser and navigate to all other users' schemas and moreover SELECT, UPDATE etc.
Which privilege I should revoke to avoid this?

I tried this

```
REVOKE select on SYS.ALL_USERS from PUBLIC
```

with no results though...

Comment: [**SELECT ANY TABLE**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/GRANT.html#GUID-20B4E2C0-A7F8-4BC8-A5E8-BE61BDC41AC3): *Query tables, views, or materialized views in any schema except SYS,AUDSYS. Obtain row locks using a SELECT ... FOR UPDATE.* **UPDATE ANY TABLE**: *Update rows in tables and views in any schema except SYS,AUDSYS.* The same for other `* ANY *` privileges

Comment: It's always better to *allow* (whitelist) privileges than *dissalow* something. So you need to start with no privileges and add one by one (avoiding `* ANY *` privileges) until you have the required minimum.

Comment: The "ANY" privileges should only be granted to administrators, never to application or end users, because they let you access *ANY* schema, by definition. You have created a super user, then asked how to remove the super user privileges. Simple: don't grant them in the first place. Literally every "System Privilege" you have listed in your script should probably be revoked.

Comment: Remove all of these grants and start over. Give CONNECT only, then add only the ones actually needed. Definitely don't give them the ANY grants, and don't give "WITH ADMIN OPTION" either. You're making all your users into DBAs.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have already commented on your question, do not use all the `GRANT` statements at the time of creation.

```
CREATE USER username  IDENTIFIED BY username  ;
-- ROLES
GRANT "CONNECT" TO username  WITH ADMIN OPTION;
ALTER USER username  DEFAULT ROLE "CONNECT";
```

You may want to add:

```
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO username;
```

But certainly not all the other privileges.